# Return multiple column values as new rows SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I had a table that shows each employee and lists the positions that they have applied for as separate columns.

```
APPNO, Date_Applied, FirstName, LastName, Position1, Position2, Position3
```

I would like to return the multiple positions applied for as additional rows for the same employee. So if one person applied for 3 different positions it would return 3 different rows for that one employee.

```
APPNO, Date_Applied, FirstName, LastName, Position1,
APPNO, Date_Applied, FirstName, LastName, Position2
APPNO, Date_Applied, FirstName, LastName, Position3
```

Answer (score 3):

Normalization is really important, but something like this would work:

```
SELECT APPNO, Date_Applied, FirstName, LastName, Position1 AS position
UNION ALL
SELECT APPNO, Date_Applied, FirstName, LastName, Position2
WHERE Position2 IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT APPNO, Date_Applied, FirstName, LastName, Position3
WHERE Position3 IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way using `CROSS APPLY`:

```
SELECT  t.APPNO,
        t.Date_Applied,
        t.FirstName,
        t.LastName,
        x.Position
FROM YourTable t
CROSS APPLY 
(
    VALUES
        (t.Position1),
        (t.Position2),
        (t.Position3)
) x (Position)
WHERE x.Position IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO but it's so much more elegant, and that's all that matters

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using SQL Server you can also use the UNPIVOT function:

```
select appono,
  date_applied,
  firstname,
  lastname,
  position
from yourtable
unpivot
(
  position
  for col in (Position1, Position2, Position3)
) unpiv
```

Answer (score 0):

is this sorta the same thing?

**select**  APPNO, DATE_APPLIED, First_Name, Last_Name, SEX, RACE, POSITIONS_APPLIED_FOR_1 [Position] 
 **from** PYAppRole.APPLICNT 
**union** 
 
**select**  APPNO, DATE_APPLIED, First_Name, Last_Name, SEX, RACE,  POSITIONS_APPLIED_FOR_2 [Position] 
**from** PYAppRole.APPLICNT 
**union** 
**select**  APPNO, DATE_APPLIED, First_Name, Last_Name, SEX, RACE, POSITIONS_APPLIED_FOR_3 [Position] 
**from** PYAppRole.APPLICNT
**union** 
**select**  APPNO, DATE_APPLIED, First_Name, Last_Name, SEX, RACE, POSITIONS_APPLIED_FOR_4 [Position] 
**from** PYAppRole.APPLICNT